# JQuery SSN Mask

Tags: jquery

How do I mask SSN in a Textbox and only show the last 4 digits of SSN when I load up a page using JQuery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're masking it with jQuery you've already got a security hole. You need to mask it server-side otherwise it's being sent unmasked across the network. That's a huge privacy and identity theft problem.

Comment: Agreed.  It is absolutely imperative that if your intention is to "obscure" the SSN and just show the last 4, that it is done on the server side.  Otherwise, the user could simply "View Source" on your page and see the unmasked SSN.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can mask your SSN Number using JS

```js
.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2').replace(/^(\d{3})-(\d{2})(.+)/, '$1-$2-$3').substring(0, 11)
```